# AWS and security groups as inbound

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I would like to do the following but it never works:

```
nginx load-balancer ec2 server (sec group sg-1111)
inbound - port:80 - all traffic

application ec2 server
inbound - port:9000 - sec group sg-1111
```

I can never seem to get the traffic to route through by specifying the secgroup of the load balancer as the only group allowed to route traffic in at that port. It just times out as if it can't send data through on that port (9000).

I assume its possible and i'm missing something.

Both servers reside within the default VPC.

Comment: 1. Please confirm that you are forwarding port 80 -> port 9000 on your load balancer. 2. In your tests, you are connecting to your nginx server using port 80, correct? 3. What are your outbound rules for the application server's security group?

Comment: 1. Yep for sure, 2. Yes correct, 3. LB: outbound - All traffic - destination: 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Does the instance get flagged as "healthy" by the ELB?  Does `netstat -n` show partially-established connections?  Does ELB return an error, and if so, how quickly?

Comment: This is a custom load balancer. Basically nginx on an ec2 server with upstream set to the application server private IP